# How does node.js require('xxx') knows which javascript file is the main entrance in xxx package?

Tags: npm, require, package.json

I'm trying to write a node module myself and publish it.
Assume the dir looks like below:

```
root/
   a.js  
   b.js  
   c.js  
   package.json
```

now a.js and b.js are required in c.js, and I want c.js to be the package interface when other developers require my package. How to specify that? I don't have a clue.

When my package is required, how does npm knows which js file is the main entrance?

Answer (score 0):

It can be specified as `main` field in `package.json`: `"main": "c.js"`

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main

By default `index.js` from package folder would be used.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules